# Erro ao fazer paginação usando PagedList com List<Dinamyc>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid, pagedlist

Estou tentando fazer a paginação de um **WebGrid** usando **PagedList** porém ocorre erro de conversão:

> Additional information: Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo
>   'PagedList.PagedList' em
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Não sei se ocorre devido a variável `dns` ser do tipo `List<dynamic>` conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ViewBag.Columns = columns;                    
                var dns = new List<dynamic>();
                dns = Util.DataTableParaDynamic.ConverterDtParaList(dt);
                int paginaTamanho = 15;
                int paginaNumero = (page);
                ViewBag.Total = dns.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho);
```

Não é necessário usar o PagedList posso usar qualquer outro meio que faça a paginação e funcione nessas condições.

Answer (score 0):

Não há necessidade de o usar o `PagedList`, basta usar o `Skip` e o `Take` que funciona perfeitamente:

```
dns = Util.DataTableParaDynamic.ConverterDtParaList(dt);
                if (dns.Count > pageNumber)
                {
                    ViewBag.Total = dns.Skip((pageSize - 1) * pageNumber)
                                        .Take(pageSize)
                                        .ToList();
                }else
                {
                    ViewBag.Total = dns;
                }
```